# how to get a single row from database and pass it to the view through controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i need to get a single row from database and have to pass that row into the view through the controller

my admin_model code is

```
function delete_student($student_id)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$student_id);
    $this->db->delete('student');

    $this->db->where('id',$student_id);
    $query=$this->db->get('student');
    $result=$query->row_array();
    $row=$result[0];

    $father=$row['father_name'];
    $mother=$row['mother_name'];
    $this->db->where(array('father_name'=>$father,'mother_name'=>$mother));
    $this->db->delete('parent');

}
```

and the controller

```
function delete_student()
{
    $student_id=$this->input->post('student_id');
    $class=$this->input->post('class');
    $this->admin_model->delete_student($student_id);
    $list["status"]="deleted";
    $list["class"]=$class;
    $list["classes"]=$this->admin_model->class_list();
    $list["students"]=$this->admin_model->student_list($class);
    $this->load->view('admin/add_student',$list);
}
```

and here, the student is getting deleted. i want to delete the corresponding parent to be deleted when the function delete_student() is called

it shows the error

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: models/admin_model.php

Comment: print ur result here

Comment: i added my result that it shows undefined offset : 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some wrong code in admin_model

check:

first you are deleting  a record where student id matches:

```
$this->db->where('id',$student_id);
$this->db->delete('student');
```

and after again you are retrieving a record:

```
$this->db->where('id',$student_id);
$query=$this->db->get('student');
$result=$query->row_array();
```

Now here your `$result` is empty because record already deleted

So error generated because of invalid index on statement:

```
 $row=$result[0];
```

try to put `if(!empty($result))` before `$row=$result[0];` and check the result.

Comment: then can i delete the parent first and then student like       $this->db->where('id',$student_id);
  $query=$this->db->get('student');
  $result=$query->row_array();
  $row=$result[0];
  
  $father=$row['father_name'];
  $mother=$row['mother_name'];
  $this->db->where(array('father_name'=>$father,'mother_name'=>$mother));
  $this->db->delete('parent');
  
  $this->db->where('id',$student_id);
  $this->db->delete('student');

Comment: Yes try that. You need to retrieve the record before deleting the record.

Comment: i added the function u suggested and now the error is not there. thanks alot and now i want to delete the parent also. is it necessary to call another function from the controller to do that?

Comment: NO need. Use only one function for that.